# The help tag - can we remove it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The [help](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/help) tag is fairly pointless and should be removed, possibly burninated. We assume most folks are asking for help.

Currently it has no usage wiki, and about 20 questions have it as a tag - none of which would suffer from its removal.

Comment: I have no issue with burninating it ... there are several tags which I've found to be useless, yet people still seem to find them, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fini, kind sir :o) (Yes, I manually burninated all of them.)